# How to "simulate" processing time consuming tasks for FreeRTOS aimed to discuss real-time system topics using Linux simulator

Tags: linux, posix, freertos

I'm trying to use FreeRTOS to discuss real time concepts with students, using the [POSIX-Linux simulator](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-simulator-for-Linux.html) framework. To accomplish this, I have to find a way of wasting processing time in a controlled way (simulating task in "Running" status by a predetermined period of processing time).

Delays are not good because they change the task status to "Block" and, with a preemptive scheduler, it means the scheduler can give the processor to other tasks. Using Linux native time control approaches (e.g. using `clock_gettime()` to build the logic) are not good because I don't have the control of the exact running time of a single task, specially with preemptiveness. Regular iterations (for, while) don't have the control I need for processing time (my computer and students computers will have different processing times depending on their architectures).

During my researches on FreeRTOS documentation, I found both the `TaskStatus_t` struct and the `vTaskGetInfo()` function which were supposed to help me out. And my problem is when I implement something like:

```
// Creating the task
if (xTaskCreate( 
    app_task,   
    task1_info.name,                            
    configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,       
    (void *) &task1_info,                           
    task1_info.priority,
    NULL 
) != pdPASS) printf("Task create error %s\n", task1_info.name);
// ...
starting_time_ticks = xTaskGetTickCount(); // starting time in ticks
vTaskStartScheduler();
// ...

static void app_task( void *pvParameters )
// The task itself
{ // ...
    for( ;; )
    { // ...
        app_proc_ticks( 
            pdMS_TO_TICKS( task_info.proc_time_ms ), 
            task_info.name
        ); // consuming processing time...
    // ... }
// ... }

static void app_proc_ticks( TickType_t proc_time_ticks,  uint8_t name[APP_MAX_MSG_SIZE])
// Consuming the number of ticks in order to attain a certain processing time
{
    TaskHandle_t xHandle;
    TaskStatus_t xTaskDetails;
    xHandle = xTaskGetHandle( name );
    configASSERT( xHandle );
    vTaskGetInfo( xHandle, &xTaskDetails, pdTRUE, eInvalid );
    TickType_t begin = xTaskDetails.ulRunTimeCounter;
    while((xTaskDetails.ulRunTimeCounter - begin) < proc_time_ticks)
    {
        vTaskGetInfo( xHandle, &xTaskDetails, pdTRUE, eInvalid );
    }
}
```

For a `task_info.proc_time_ms` equal to **25 ms**, my code shows up as the task is consuming **around 250 ms** worth of ticks, a error factor of 10x. The way I count this is with the following "timestamp" strategy:

```
static TickType_t get_timestamp_ticks() {
    return xTaskGetTickCount() - starting_time_ticks;
}
```

As far as I can see, I'm having problems to understand and properly convert `xTaskDetails.ulRunTimeCounter` time unit (ticks, ms, or probably something else). Also probably some tick to ms constant I'm not aware of. Right now, to convert from "ms" to "ticks" I'm using `pdMS_TO_TICKS()` macro and to convert from "ticks" to "ms" I'm multiplying the number of ticks by `portTICK_RATE_MS`.

Also, after `make`, I'm using `taskset -c 0 ./build/posix_demo` to run and ensure the use of a single processor by my executable.

I'm not trying to hold on to this solution, though. If anyone could share how to do a time controlled delay with "real consumption of processing time" for tasks in FreeRTOS, I would appreciate it as well.